# jira search ascending oldest to newest.

Tags: jira, jira-agile

This currently is my search for lira issues "project in ("project a", "project b") AND status not in (Resolved, Closed) ORDER BY createdDate".

What would I have to change or add to make it so it is ascending which would display issues starting with the oldest ticket to the newest ticket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would simply add "ASC" to the ORDER BY clause, like this:

```
project in ("project a", "project b") AND status not in (Resolved, Closed) ORDER BY createdDate ASC
```

Comment: Thank you.  That is exactly what I wanted to know.